# Why XPlot charts are not rendered?

Tags: f#, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to render some Geo charts by following one of the tutorials but instead of getting a chart, I get a `XPlot.GoogleCharts.GoogleChart`. I am using jupyter notebook on localhost, therefore I am `#load`'ing modules from my computer.

Cell 1:

```
#load "/home/<name>/Downloads/IfSharp.v3.0.1/XPlot.Plotly.Paket.fsx"
#load "/home/<name>/Downloads/IfSharp.v3.0.1/XPlot.Plotly.fsx"
```

Cell 2:

```
Paket.Package ["FsLab"]
#load "/home/<name>/Downloads/IfSharp.v3.0.1/Paket.Generated.Refs.fsx"
```

Cell 3:

```
open System
open FSharp.Data
open XPlot.GoogleCharts
```

Cell 4:

```
let wb = WorldBankData.GetDataContext()
```

Cell 5:

```
let emissions =
 [ for c in wb.Countries do
   let v = c.Indicators.``CO2 emissions (kt)``.[2010]
   if not(Double.IsNaN(v)) then yield c.Name, v ]
```

Cell 6:

```
Chart.Geo(emissions)
|> Chart.WithLabels ["Name"; "Emissions (total kt)"]
|> Chart.WithOptions
    (Options(colorAxis=ColorAxis(colors= [|"#6CC627"; "#DB9B3B"; "#DB7532"; "#DD5321"; "#DB321C"; "#E00B00"; |] )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code probably is missing a `#load` try adding this:

```
#load "XPlot.GoogleCharts.fsx"
```

I also changed your code a bit to take care of missing temperatures:

```
let getTomorrowTemp place =
  try 
    let w = Weather.Load(forecastUrl + place)
    let tomorrow = Seq.head w.List
    let temp = tomorrow.Temp.Max
    printfn "Getting temperature in: %s %A" place temp
    (place, temp)
    |> Some
  with _ -> None

let worldTemps =
  [ for c in wb.Countries do
      let place = c.Name
      match getTomorrowTemp place with
      | Some v -> yield v
      | None   -> ()
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you once again @Amieres